# VS code extensions crashed when i working on angular typescript project

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

[Actual error in the developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMORC.png)

[Memory consumption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI5Lm.png)

i'm using tslint plugin in vscode. "Extension has stopped working" error shows in vscode notification.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid posting links to off-site resources. Right now, you can not post pictures, but once you gain some reputation, you will receive the rights to do so. Until then, please post text. Also, your first image contains just text. It is considers bad practice to post text / code as image. Please post it as text.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to restart your computer. Telling us what your code is doing, could help.